# Listener is not triggering in Laravel Pusher

Tags: php, pusher

I have been following [this guide](https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel) to create a chat system using Pusher. It works however I only receive any new messages from others when I refresh the page which is very annoying. I have tried numbers of things however none of them actually solved the issue. I really feel like it's something super simple which I have overlooked. If someone could help me out that would be amazing!

As you can see the messages get send, users can successfully connect and subscribe:
[image]
**.env**

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

**MessageSent.php**

```
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * User that sent the message
     *
     * @var User
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * Message details
     *
     * @var Message
     */
    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, Message $message)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chat');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'MessageSent';
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        messages: []
    },

    created() {
        this.fetchMessages();

        Echo.private('chat').listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
            this.sentMessages.push({
                message: e.message.message,
                user: e.user
            });
        });
    },

    methods: {
        fetchMessages() {
            axios.get('/messages').then(response => {
                this.messages = response.data;
            });
        },

        addMessage(message) {
            this.messages.push(message);

            axios.post('/messages', message).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

`created()` only fires once when the pages refreshes as I checked this with a `console.log`. In addition, the console.log in `Echo.private()` isn't reached at all whether I do.

**ChatsController.php**

```
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show chats
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('chat');
    }

    /**
     * Fetch all messages
     *
     * @return Message
     */
    public function fetchMessages()
    {
        return Message::with('user')->get();
    }

    /**
     * Persist message to database
     *
     * @param  Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function sendMessage(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $message = $user->messages()->create([
            'message' => $request->input('message')
        ]);

        broadcast(new MessageSent($user, $message))->toOthers();

        return ['status' => 'Message Sent!'];
    }
}
```

Also I have uncommented *App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider* in *config/app.php*

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it. I figured out that the issue was caused due to changing the app name using `php artisan app:name <name here>`. Therefore I changed it back to App using the command: `php app:name App`